# Read program's config file under ~/.config when program needs to run as sudo

Tags: c, linux

I'm building a program in C that reads it's configurations from the user's config directory and it gets the `~` path using `getenv("HOME")`. Since this program needs root privileges if I run it as a `sudo` the `getenv("HOME")` changes and I can't read the configurations file under `~/.config`.
Right now I have 2 ideas in my mind how can I do that:

1. To change the ownership of the program to root, then give it suid permission for user, which I think is not very recommended since it can cause vulnerabilities.
2. To run program with `sudo`, get the name if the logged user using `getlogin()` then I can make the `~` path by gluing `/home/getlogin() return address/`. Bu the truth I'm a little bit afraid of this solution and I don't know how relevant it is.

So I'm here guys to ask for some ideas if that possible.
Thanks for you time.

Update:
Maybe it is good to note that the specific part which requires the root privileges is the part of the code which executes program that requires these privileges from `/usr/bin` using a function that forks from parent process then execute the program using `execv()`.

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be `sudo`? That's usually best avoided.

Comment: Yup, I'm sure since the program needs to execute few things from /usr/bin that requires root priviliges.

Comment: @yankh18 Executing a binary in `/usr/bin` doesn't require root privileges in most cases.

Comment: I know but the things I'm going to execute from ```/usr/bin``` requires that unfortunately @Andy Sukowski-Bang.

Comment: `the things I'm going to execute from /usr/bin requires that unfortunately` sooo why not execute only that program with `sudo`? And why not tell us what program is that exactly? You could also take the path to user home directory as an argument. The "proper" design, would be to have a service running as root that listens for events for example on dbus, and user client that sends events to be executed as root (ie. I think that's how firewalld-applet or NetworkManager solve it). But this may depend on what problem _exactly_ are you trying to solve.

Comment: I would gladly tell @KamilCuk. So I'm building rsync and few other tools wrapper and helper program in C (its actually a strange choice becuase it would be a lot easier to build it in python, but i like C and I would like to practice it more). This program uses another program that i made for configurations management. So every time I make a system backup I also make some housekeeping for my system, so this program purpose to make my life easier and automate all this cleaning and backing up process in only one program.

Comment: I don't think it'll help here, but as a general rule, use [`wordexp(3)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) to do tilde expansion.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone who will face the same problem I managed to get an solution for executing program from `/usr/bin/` without technically prepending `sudo` at the beginning of the program which will change the `getenv("HOME")` path.
So lets say I have this function that forks and run a program:

```
/*
*This function will fork the parent process to create a
*child process then execute commands using one of the exec
*familie's functions. Return -1 for fork failure, 1 for execv() 
*failure, otherwise 0.
*/
int exec_command(const char *prog_name, char *commands[]) {
    char prog_path[strlen("/usr/bin/")+strlen(prog_name)];
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t ret;

    sprintf(prog_path, "/usr/bin/%s", prog_name);
    pid = fork(); //Create a new child process
    if(pid == -1) {//If failed to create new child
        fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while creating a child process.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if(pid != 0) { //If child process didnt start
        while((ret = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) == -1) { //Wait for child
            if(errno != EINTR) { //If the waitpid() error isnt an interrupte signal
                fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while waiting for the child process.\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        if(execv(prog_path, commands)==-1) //If command wasnt found
            return 1;
    return 0; 
}
```

And for example I want to install a package using `pacman` (which obviously requires root privileges), I can do something like this:

```
int main() {
   char *command[] = {   
      "sudo", "pacman", //Sudo is the program name, pacman is the program i want to execute using sudo.    
      "-S", "package_name", NULL   
   };

   exec_command(command[0], command);   
   return 0;
}
```

This way I manged to execute program that requires root privileges without prepending sudo when executing my program which gives me the chance to get user's home path before calling the `exec_command()` because `sudo` won't be executed before this point.